# Queda mal anidar consultas de AJAX?

Tags: ajax, nodejs

estoy armando el jquery que consultaria a una API que armé, la cual tiene 3 rutas...

Queda mal que anide las 3 consultas de AJAX?

onda el codigo quedaria

```
$.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:8000/getSummonerId?",
      data:{summoner : summoner, host : host} ,
      beforesend : function(){
        console.log("mandando consulta");
      },
      success: function(respuesta){
        console.log(respuesta.accountId)
        accId += respuesta.accountId;
        console.log(accId);
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8000/getSummonerId?",
            data:{summoner : summoner, host : host} ,
            beforesend : function(){
            console.log("mandando consulta");
            },
            success: function(respuesta){
                console.log(respuesta.accountId)
                accId += respuesta.accountId;
                console.log(accId);
                $("#showResultado").text(accId);
                $(".loader").hide();
                $("#showResultado").show();
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("no se ha podido obtener la info");
            }
        });
      },
      error: function(){
        console.log("no se ha podido obtener la info");
      }
    });
```

esto mas que nada es un ejemplo del codigo, sé que hay cosas repetidas....

Comment: Si te funciona déjalo así. Para mejorarlo que podrías hacer es manejarlo utilizando "sync" "await" de javascript, puedes buscar en Google y hay mucha información sobre eso. Sino trata de mejorar tu backend para no tener que realizar dos consultas y satisfacer todos los requerimientos con una sola.

Comment: si, intenté hacerlo en una sola consulta y no funcionaba, asi que logré arreglar la api para que haga diferentes consultas a traves de varias rutas.
Pero, sacando de lado si funciona o no, queda bien hacerlo asi?

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Si esta bien hacerlo de esa manera

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes es manejable hasta cierto punto, pero también es el inicio de un [*Callback Hell*](https://codearmy.co/que-es-el-callback-hell-y-como-evitarlo-4af418a6ed14).

Te recomiendo modificar (refactorizar) tu código para evitarlo ahora que estás a tiempo, usando Promesas o su equivalente en jQuery, algo como lo siguiente:

**Nota**: No lo he probado y posiblemente tenga erratas. Además suelo usar el API [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) y no estoy totalmente familiarizado con jQuery.ajax() y su [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), pero debería servirte como guía.

```
function error(){
  console.log("no se ha podido obtener la info");
}

$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/getSummonerId?",
  data:{summoner : summoner, host : host} ,
  beforesend : function(){
    console.log("mandando consulta");
  }
}).then(function(respuesta) {
  console.log(respuesta.accountId)
  accId += respuesta.accountId;
  console.log(accId);
  return $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8000/getSummonerId?",
    data:{summoner : summoner, host : host} ,
    beforesend : function(){
      console.log("mandando consulta");
    }
  });
}).then(function(respuesta){
    console.log(respuesta.accountId)
    accId += respuesta.accountId;
    console.log(accId);
    $("#showResultado").text(accId);
    $(".loader").hide();
    $("#showResultado").show();
}).fail(error);
```

Usando fetch y async/await sería hasta más sencillo y no necesitas librerías:

```
async function tresLlamadas() {

   let respuesta1 = await fetch('http://...', {...});
   //... obtenemos datos de la respuesta1 para hacer una nueva petición
   let respuesta2 = await fetch('http://...', {...});
   //... obtenemos datos de la respuesta2 para hacer una nueva petición
   let respuesta3 = await fetch('http://...', {...});
   return ...;
}

tresLlamadas().then(function(resultado) { ...});
```