# Peticiones anidadas Ajax que no se ejecutan

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Realizo una primera petición Ajax a la que anido una segunda y posteriormente a esta le anido otra. Las tres hacen el mismo tipo de operación y el código es exactamente igual salvo que se usan otras variables. Realizan la petición a la misma página y ejecutan el mismo método web en ella. Este método tiene seis parámetros. Veo depurando que la primera petición se ejecuta, pero las dos siguientes no. No logro encontrar el motivo puesto que la acción que realizan es idéntica y la estructura de la petición es igual, solo que la segunda está anidada a la primera y la tercera a la segunda.

Lo que me gustaría es encontrar qué aspecto en la estructura de mi código de las tres peticiones está incorrecto para que las dos peticiones anidadas no se ejecuten. Las variables que se pasan en las peticiones tienen un valor comprobado. No pretendo que examinéis conceptualmente el código, solo agradecería una revisión de la sintaxis.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{"parametro":"set_session","valor":"ca_imp","tabla":"' + ca_imp + '","campo":"","criterio":"","v1":""}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (devolucion) {
            if (devolucion.d) {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  data: '{"parametro":"set_session","valor":"cpo_imp","tabla":"' + cpo_imp + '","campo":"","criterio":"","v1":""}',
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (devolucion) {
                      if (devolucion.d) {
                          $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
                              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                              data: '{"parametro":"set_session","valor":"cpd_imp","tabla":"' + cpd_imp + '","campo":"","criterio":"","v1":""}',
                              dataType: "json",
                              success: function (devolucion) {
                                  if (devolucion.d) {
                                  }
                              },
                              error: function (req, status, error) {
                                  alert("No hubo respuesta desde el servidor. Prueba otra vez.");
                              }
                          });
                      }
                  },
                  error: function (req, status, error) {
                      alert("No hubo respuesta desde el servidor. Prueba otra vez.");
                  }
              });
            }
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert("No hubo respuesta desde el servidor. Prueba otra vez.");
        }
    });
```

Saludos

Comment: Yo haria lo que ponen en esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233650/jquery-nested-ajax-calls-formatting  para que quede más claro todo

Comment: Hola! He hecho lo que me propones, pero sigue funcionando igual. Realmente el cambio no supone realmente nada a nivel funcional, ya que cambiar devolucion por result y comprobar el valor devolucion.d de la primera o "ok" de la segunda arrojan el mismo resultado. Muchas gracias

Comment: He comprobado que el problema no se produce por el modo de hacer la estructura condicional en la propiedad success. La suprimí directamente para ver si se ejecutaba de cualquier forma la petición anidada pero no se ejecutaba tampoco. Lo extraño es que no me dispara la alerta que tengo puesta en caso de error.

Comment: Una versión en español de lo comentado por @masterguru: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/334324/queda-mal-anidar-consultas-de-ajax/334337#334337

Comment: Los success solo se ejecutan si la peticion da ok. Prueba a usar complete que se ejecuta aunque es status no sea ok y tal vez obtengas mas feedback

Comment: Tiene pienta de que la respuesta tiene el estado 200 pero no contiene el atributo `d`

Comment: ¿Ya probaste imprimiendo que te devuelven las peticiones?, quiza devolucion.d no está devolviendo el valor que esperas

Comment: Hola a todos y gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Fernando, sí, el valor que devuelve la primera petición lo puedo ver son un alert(). Devuelve el valor esperado. La segunda y al tercera petición no se ejecutan, porque inspecciono el método web y no se detiene; sin embargo con la primera petición sí.

Comment: Pablo, no puedo tener ningún atributo puesto que ni siquiera se ejecuta la petición

Comment: Hernán, con if (devolucion.d) { } puedo hacer peticiones en otras funciones del proyecto y no tengo ningún problema. Cuando se devuelve un valor entonces se cumple (existe devolucion.d) y se ejecuta lo contenido en success. Pero en este caso es que no se realiza la petición. Ese es el problema. La cuestión es por qué, puesto que está hecha de la misma forma y hacia el mismo método web. Con los mismos seis parámetros.

Comment: La primera petición devuelve el valor esperado y lo imprimo en la consola (un string). La petición se realiza. Pero cuando llega a success no ocurre nada con la condición if. El código pasa a las líneas que siguen y obvia las dos peticiones.

Comment: Ya encontré el problema. Lo pongo como respuesta para quien pueda servirle. Muchas gracias a todos!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en algo que aún me sigue sucediendo con el manejo de las peticiones Ajax. Y es que aquello que está fuera del código específico de la petición Ajax se va a ejecutar con normalidad de forma síncrona. En la pregunta que he formulado las dos peticiones anidadas no es que no se ejecutaran, sino que la interferencia del código siguiente a las peticiones estaba haciéndome creer que jamás se ejecutaban las peticiones segunda y tercera. Pero una vez finalizado el restante código he podido imprimir los valores devueltos y efectivamente se realizan las peticiones. Ahora tengo cuatro peticiones, incluyendo la que estaba fuera del anidamiento anterior como  la tercera petición anidada. Como no se realiza hasta que se realice la tercera ahora todo lo que se tenía que hacer en esa petición sucede satisfactoriamente y con los valores de variables del servidor correctamente actualizadas previamente por las peticiones anteriores. Pongo el código como ha quedado funcionando. Por esa razón antes no recibía ningún error. Las peticiones se realizaban. Había además otro factor que me estaba confundiendo. La operación del código síncrono necesita bastante tiempo para finalizarse, y eso en un principio me llevaba a pensar que las peticiones anidadas habían desaparecido. Al final todo arreglado.

```
function importaralumnos() {
    
    var ca_imp = prompt("Curso académico de los alumnos a importar en formato nnnn/mmmm");
    var cpo_imp = prompt("Código del profesor de los alumnos a importar");
    var cpd_imp = prompt("Código del profesor al que se asignarán los alumnos a importar");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{"parametro":"set_session","valor":"ca_imp","tabla":"' + ca_imp + '","campo":"","criterio":"","v1":""}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (devolucion) {
            if (devolucion.d) {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  data: '{"parametro":"set_session","valor":"cpo_imp","tabla":"' + cpo_imp + '","campo":"","criterio":"","v1":""}',
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (devolucion) {
                      if (devolucion.d) {
                          $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
                              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                              data: '{"parametro":"set_session","valor":"cpd_imp","tabla":"' + cpd_imp + '","campo":"","criterio":"","v1":""}',
                              dataType: "json",
                              success: function (devolucion) {
                                  if (devolucion.d) {
                                      $.ajax({
                                          type: "POST",
                                          url: "Respuestaajax.aspx/Respuestaaj",
                                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                          data: '{"parametro":"funcion","valor":"importaralumnos","tabla":"","campo":"","criterio":"","v1":""}',
                                          dataType: "json",
                                          success: function (devolucion) {
                                              if (devolucion.d) {
                                                  window.document.body.style.opacity = "1";
                                                  alert("La importación se ha realizado satisfactoriamente.");  //mensaje final       
                                              }
                                          },
                                          error: function (req, status, error) {
                                              alert("No hubo respuesta desde el servidor. Prueba otra vez.");
                                          }
                                      });
                                  }
                              },
                              error: function (req, status, error) {
                                  alert("No hubo respuesta desde el servidor. Prueba otra vez.");
                              }
                          });
                      }
                  },
                  error: function (req, status, error) {
                      alert("No hubo respuesta desde el servidor. Prueba otra vez.");
                  }
              });
            }
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert("No hubo respuesta desde el servidor. Prueba otra vez.");
        }
    });
}
```